# How to format the units to avoid decimal points?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

One of graph, I display the number of persons in each category, so the axis is ordinal. 
If I put `10` ticks and `elasticX`, it starts with a max number of several hundreds, and each tick as a good number.

However, if I click on other charts and I filter until the max category has only 5 persons, the tick will be a `0,5 | 1 | 1,5 | 2...`

It obviously looks silly to display an option of 1.5 person. Is there a way to adjust the number of ticks so it doesn't display a `step < 1`?

Comment: Found the solution for D3, maybe DS have the same features? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576906/d3-tick-marks-on-integers-only

Comment: Yes, the axis in dc.js is straight from d3, so this is really a d3 question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pure d3 solution, thanks for the tip:

```
.tickFormat(d3.format("d"))
```