# Need to have only integers in x-axis - d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[image]

I am facing issue in order to have integer values in x-axis(graph shown in above link). x-axis should be divided as 1,2,3 but it is getting divided as 0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6,...,2.8 ,3.0 .
I have the following code:

```
private initSvg() {
    d3.select("#svg1")
      .attr("width", document.getElementById("svg1").parentElement.offsetWidth - 300 - this.margin.left - this.margin.right)
      .attr("height", (document.getElementById("svg1").parentElement.offsetWidth / 3))
    this.svg = d3.select('#svg1');
    this.width = document.getElementById("svg1").parentElement.offsetWidth - 300 - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
    // this.height = +this.svg.attr("height") - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;
    this.height = (document.getElementById("svg1").parentElement.offsetHeight - 100)
    // console.log(this.width, this.height)
    this.g = this.svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + (this.margin.left + 100) + "," + this.margin.top + ")");
  }

  private initAxis() {
    this.y = d3Scale.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, this.height]).padding(0.1);
    this.x = d3Scale.scaleLinear().rangeRound([this.width, 0]);
    this.y.domain(this.STATISTICS.map((d) => d.qua));
    this.x.domain([d3Array.max(this.STATISTICS, (d) => d.value + 2), 0]);

  }

  private drawAxis() {
    this.g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + this.height + ")")
      .call(d3Axis.axisBottom(this.x).tickSize(-this.height))
      .selectAll("text")
      .attr("dy", "1em")
      .selectAll("path")
      .attr("class", "opac")
      .style("stroke-opacity", "0")
    this.g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y")
      // .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (- ((document.getElementById("svg1").parentElement.offsetWidth / 3) * 10) / 100) + ")")
      .call(d3Axis.axisLeft(this.y).tickSize(-this.width))
      .append("text")
      .attr("class", "axis-title")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", "0.71em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")

  }

  private drawBars() {
    var i = 0;
    var trans = this.g.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(this.STATISTICS)
      .enter().append("rect")
      .style("fill", (d: any) => { i++; return this.colorrange[i]; })
      .attr("y", (d) => this.y(d.qua))
      .attr("height", (this.y.bandwidth()))
    // .attr("height", 60)
    trans.transition()
      .duration(2000)
      .delay(function (d, i) {
        return i * 50;
      })
      .attr("x", (d) => 0 /*this.x(d.AverageValue)*/)
      .attr("width", (d) => /* this.height -*/ this.x((d.value == "" ? 0 : d.value)))

  }

  private drawLabel() {
    this.g.selectAll('.label')
      .data(this.STATISTICS)
      .enter().append('text')
      .attr('class', (d) => this.x(d.value) < 50 ? 'label bar-value-2' : 'label bar-value')
      .style('font-size', (d) => (this.y.bandwidth() < 30 ? this.y.bandwidth() * 0.7 : 14) + 'px')
      // .attr('x', (d) => this.x(d.AverageValue) < 40 ? 40 : this.x(d.AverageValue) - 7)
      .attr('x', 100)
      .attr('y', (d) => this.y(d.qua) + this.y.bandwidth() * 0.5 + 6);

  }
```

And I am calling all this in a different method to get result:

```
setTimeout(() => {
            this.initSvg()
            this.initAxis()
            this.drawAxis()
            this.drawBars()
            this.drawLabel()
          }, 500);
```

Note:

```
STATISTICS = [
{qua: "Yes", value: 1}
{qua: "No", value: 1},
];
```

Tried to change something in x-domain but it didn't worked. Honestly, I am new to d3 and that's why don't know where to make changes.

Need further assistance.
Thanks.

Comment: `axis.ticks()`: find the integers in the x-domain and feed it to the `ticks` function of the axis

Comment: I tried to update drawAxis() method like this:                                                                `private drawAxis() {
    this.g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + this.height + ")")
      .call(d3Axis.axisBottom(this.x).tickSize(-this.height))
      .ticks(3)`                                                                                                                    But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: oops `axis.tickValues`

Comment: @rioV8 Please let me know that where and how to apply tickValues. Thanks

Comment: @Mr.A see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56821215/5812238)