# Cannot set d3 axis to only integers

Tags: typescript, d3.js, axis, axis-labels

I've looked at a couple of answers on here:

1. [how-to-limit-d3-svg-axis-to-integer-labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643591/how-to-limit-d3-svg-axis-to-integer-labels)
2. [d3-tick-marks-on-integers-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576906/d3-tick-marks-on-integers-only?rq=1)

But they're not working for me.

I have an array of years, for example:

```
years: Array<number> = [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017];
let minXAxis = Math.min(...this.years);
let maxXAxis = Math.max(...this.years);

this.xScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([this.margins.left, this.width - this.margins.right]).domain([minXAxis, maxXAxis]);

this.xAxis = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis axis-x")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${this.height - this.margins.bottom})`)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(this.xScale));
```

Doing just this gives me the following.

[image: pic]

Then when I used `.tickFormat(d3.format("d"))` like so:

```
this.xAxis = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis axis-x")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${this.height - this.margins.bottom})`)
  // set to only display ticks for digits
  .call(d3.axisBottom(this.xScale).tickFormat(d3.format("d")));
```

I get the following

[image: pic 2]

As you can see, it got rid of the decimal, but it still lists as duplicates, e.g 2011, 2011, ...

How do I fix this so the x axis only shows: 2010, 2011, 2012, ...?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56821215/5812238)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is **no** duplicate in that axis: those are values that just *seem* to be the same because you got rid of the decimals.

The problem here is simple: you are using the wrong scale for the task. You should use a time scale or, if you want to treat those years as qualitative (categorical) variables, you should use an ordinal scale (like `d3.scalePoint`) instead.

Have in mind that a year is not a regular number: `2012` is a year, but what is `2012.2412223`? If you use a linear scale you are treating those years exactly like this: pure numbers.

Therefore, the solution is just dropping the linear scale and using a time scale (or an ordinal scale).

However, if (for whatever reason) you want to stick with the linear scale and treat the years like numbers (which they are not), use `tickValues` to make sure that only the values in the `years` array will show up in the axis:

```
d3.axisBottom(this.xScale)
    .tickValues(years)
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var years = [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017];
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain(d3.extent(years))
  .range([20, 480]);
var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)
  .tickValues(years)
  .tickFormat(d3.format("d"));
var gX = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)");
axis(gX);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="100"></svg>
```

Comment: Your suggestion for tickValues() worked. I tried scaleTime() but it didn't work. Maybe I did it wrong? Also, your example doesn't work, I get unmatched parameters or something for the domain() call

Comment: @itsbavu You should try the time scale... the problem, however, is that it's not simply a matter of changing the scale, it involves a lot more, like parsing the dates for instance.

Comment: Can you update your answer with an example of that? I tried d3.timeParse("%Y"), but it's looking for a string, whereas I just have an array of numbers representing the years.

Comment: Since this is a different issue, I suggest you post *another* question.